# Nested Join with Laravel 4.0

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am struggling to build the following nested complex query with Laravel Query Builder. I am using laravel 4.0. The main problem with nested join.

```sql
SELECT clubs.id, clubs.slug, clubs.name as `club_name`, clubs.state, clubs.category, clubs.live, `m`.`total_members`, `m`.`online_members`, `m`.`offline_members`, `m`.`last_7days_members` as `total_members_last_7days`

            FROM clubs

            LEFT JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT id, club_id, count(*) as `total_members`, SUM(online_member = 1) AS online_member 

                    FROM members 

                    LEFT JOIN

                        (
                            SELECT posts.id, posts.member_id, posts.title, posts.body 
                            FROM posts 
                            WHERE posts.transaction_id IS NOT NULL

                        ) p on p.member_id = members.id
                    WHERE (`post_verfied` is null or `post_verfied` = 1) 
                        AND `members`.`deleted_at` is null
                    group by club_id
                ) m on m.club_id = clubs.id

            LEFT JOIN comments on comments.member_id = m.id

            WHERE clubs.`deleted_at` is null
            group by `clubs`.name
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You can aproach that with `DB:raw` as follows:

```
DB:table('table1')->leftJoin(DB::raw('(select * 
                             from table2 
                             join table3 on table3.id = table2.id) as mytable'),
function($join)
{
    $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'mytable.id');
});
```

I know that is not what exactly you want but it's a partial solution. Investigating I found Laravel 4.x doesn't support. There was a [pull](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/940) about that a year ago in Laravel 3.x but it was not implemented at the end. You can see anyways all the options you can aply with query builder in `Builder.php`.

Also you can use `DB:statement` when you cannot perform a complicated query with Query Builder or Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i am looking for a solution for nested joins.

Comment: Actually that is not implemented in the current version of Laravel. That really gets my attention and I hope in future versions that kind of joins are implemented. Anyways, remember the framework is not omnipotent, there are many limitations and actually nested joins is one of that. I recommend you to use `DB::statement` for that complicated querys.

Comment: I am using DB:SELECT(). any difference between DB::statement and DB::Select?

Comment: With `DB::statement` you can run any kind of queries (select, update, drop, etc). For the query you specified in your question it's ok you use `DB::select` because you want retrieve data.